# Google Maps Javascript API: TypeError: response.data[0].geometry.location.lat is not a function

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I successfully get an answer from the Google Map Javascript Api and try to access the values of the google.maps.GeocoderResult to extract the latitude and longitude from the GeocoderGeometry / LatLng

I implemented response.data[0].geometry.location.lat(), following the TSD definition, which lead, while debugging in Chrome, to the error:

```
  TypeError: response.data[0].geometry.location.lat is not a function
```

Having a look at the object in the debugger, show effectively that no method lat() or lng() aren't supported.

I could access to response.data[0].geometry.location.lat to successfully get the value in the debugger, but then my code isn't Typescript conform anymore.

Of course I could cast the result but still would like to understand the reason. Furthermore maybe someone has got an explanation and proposition of solution?

Best regards

For the record, the typescript definition:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/0e139d5d4681b71d53a30408efcc64b79eed6354/googlemaps/google.maps.d.ts

Update with chrome debug info:

```
response.data[0].geometry.location.lat() => <not available>
response.data[0].geometry.location.lat: 47.37793800000001

response.data[0].geometry.location: Object
  lat: 47.37793800000001
  lng: 8.5401898

 response.data[0].geometry: Object
    location:Object
      lat:47.377
      lng: 8.5401898
```

stacktrace of the error:

```
TypeError: response.data[0].geometry.location.lat is not a function
at interestsParamsCtrl.js:61
at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:29127)
at ionic.bundle.js:29143
at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30395)
at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:30211)
at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30503)
at done (ionic.bundle.js:24824)
at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:25022)
at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (ionic.bundle.js:24963)
```

Update 2: To query the API I do a GET and let the response be parsed

```
search(searchLocationTerm:string):ng.IPromise<{}> {
  var deferred = this.$q.defer();

  this.$http.get(Resources.Constants.Default.GOOGLE.API.URL,
    {
      params: {
        address: searchLocationTerm,
        key: Resources.Constants.Default.GOOGLE.API.KEY
      }
    })
    .success((response:Communication.IGeocoder) => {
      deferred.resolve(response);
    }).error((response:Communication.IGeocoder) => {
      deferred.reject(response);
  });

  return deferred.promise;
};
```

Where IGeocoder is

```
export interface IGeocoder {
  results:google.maps.GeocoderResult[];
  status:google.maps.GeocoderStatus;
}
```

Comment: Fix the Typescript definition and send a pull request?

Comment: Could have a try, but I read that effectively response.data[0].geometry.location.lat() should be use, that's why I would like to figure out why that error happens while debugging

Comment: What is `response.data[0].geometry.location` if you output it to the console?

Comment: I used to have similar error message, when I used `LatLngLiteral` instead of `LatLng` object. Maybe your error also comes because of this.

Comment: Thx that a good hints. I updated the details of my question. As you see I don't manipulate the answer. I do a get and the response is then parser. That would mean that the response is wrongly parsed to a LatLngLiteral instead of an LatLng? Or that the TSD definition is wrong, where it should use LatLngLiteral instead of LatLng in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending a web service request via AJAX. Please note that response of web service Geocoding API is a JSON object as specified in the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=en#GeocodingResponses

You should use a client side geocoding service instead to get an object compliant with definitions in google.maps.d.ts

Look at this [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) and client-side [geocoder service documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding).

Comment: Thx. So if I understand correctly, it would mean I'm "misusing" the google.maps.d.ts typescript definition because this definition describe service objects ("with methods") where my http get "only" returns me JSON objects ("without methods"). So in my case I should write my own tsd definition file right?

Comment: P.S.:  thx for the example, but I don't have a "map" in my client, it's about an autocomplete component. In that case I think I should use the service that way with http.get

Comment: Correct, if you look at the source code of google.maps.d.ts you will see that the first line says `Type definitions for Google Maps JavaScript API 3.20`. You do not use Maps JavaScript API, you use Geocoding API, so this definition file is not appliable. Do you implement your own autocomplete or use the autocomplete widget of Maps JavaScript API?

Comment: Thx a lot for the confirmation, fully understand now. I'll mark your answer as the good one. Not my own autocomplete, I followed some tutorial and solutions here on stack overflow.